# No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis

My program is written in Java 8, when I use the type of LocalDateTime, it will give me the following error:

> No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
>   at [Source: [B@5976fe6f; line: 1, column: 80] (through reference chain: com.boot.framwork.entity.UserInfo["accessTime"])

The entity is like this:

```
public class UserInfo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String username;

private int age;

private LocalDateTime accessTime;

private Date time;

private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

private boolean isMarried;

public UserInfo() {

}
```

It worked when I didn't use LocalDateTime

Comment: I use redis as cache

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me, that you don't have a JSR310 support. Jackson need some additional configuration to be able to recognize Java 8 Date&Time API data types. You can add it via project dependencies, just add a dependency on [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

or if you use a Gradle

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.7.4'
```

Since you use SpringBoot, this should be enough, hence not, create a Bean of type JSR310Module manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and needed `MyCustomClass` to be taken in and out of the `Lambda Function` correctly so that it can be passed through my `State Machine` in the `Step Function` without any hiccups.

I used the following post to come up with the best answer for me:

[AWS Lambda json deserialization with jackson annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480472/aws-lambda-json-deserialization-with-jackson-annotations)

And this is my code that worked for me:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

public class StaticSearchPagingLambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

    LambdaLogger logger = null;
    MyCustomClass myCustomClass = null;

    // Register the JavaTimeModule for LocalDate conversion
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) {    

            myCustomClass = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, MyCustomClass .class);

            // ...
            // Do stuff with myCustomClass
            // ...

            objectMapper.writeValue(outputStream, myCustomClass);
    }
}
```

Even though the JSON string will print out differently with the `ObjectMapper` writing to the `OutPutStream`, when the next lambda function takes it in while going through the `Step Function`, it will still get converted to `LocalDate` correctly.

Make sure that in `MyCustomClass` your `toString()` method prints correctly. My `toString()` method looks like this:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SimpleSearch {

    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;

    // ...
    // Getters and Setters for the LocalDate variables
    // ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new JSONObject(this).toString();
    }

    public SimpleSearch() {}
}
```

then your JSON printouts will always look like this when it gets sent to the lambda and not that other crazy `Jackson` format:

```
{
    "startDate": "2018-11-01",
    "endDate": "2018-11-16"
}
```

Some of the Maven dependencies I used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Hopefully AWS fixes the `Jackson` conversions to be reciprocal, to and from JSON, so that we wouldn't have to resort to these custom conversions anymore.