# AWS Lambda json deserialization with jackson annotations

Tags: java, jackson, aws-lambda

I'm calling an aws lambda with a json body. So the fields of the json are with different name from the ones in the POJO. So what I did is to add @JsonProperty on the fields to tell jackson what are the names in json. But for some reason it seems that it doesn't recognize them and all the fields are null. If I pass a json with the same field names as the POJO it's working. Here's my class:

```
public class Event implements Identifiable {

    @JsonProperty("distinct_id")
    private String distinctId;

    @JsonProperty("user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime eventDateTime;

    //Here are the getters and setters
}
```

If I pass

```
{"distinct_id":"123", "user_id":123, "dt":"2017-01-04T08:45:04+00:00"}
```

all the fields are null and with distinctId, userId, eventDateTime it's serializing ok with the exception that it also doesn't recognize my custom serializers/deserializers but this actually is the same problem.

My conclusion is that for some reason the aws jackson is not working with the annotations but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Where you able to get it to work?

Comment: @Raja I added an answer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So I found a way to do this. You need to implement RequestStreamHandler which gives you input and output streams which you can work with:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler

public class ChartHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        DeserializationClass deserializedInput = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, DeserializationClass.class)
        objectMapper.writeValue(outputStream, deserializedInput); //write to the outputStream what you want to return
    }

}
```

Having the input and output streams makes you independent of the format and frameworks you use to parse it.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at this quote from AWS documentation:

> You shouldn't rely on any other features of serialization frameworks such as annotations. If you need to customize the serialization behavior, you can use the raw byte stream to use your own serialization.

From: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-req-resp.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing that comment. The citation is not present in the current documentation of java-programming-model-req-resp  but it's probably still true

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have version mismatch between annotation types, and databind (`ObjectMapper`): both MUST be the same major version. Specifically, Jackson 1.x annotations work with Jackson 1.x databind; and 2.x with 2.x.

Difference is visible via Java package: Jackson 1.x uses `org.codehaus.jackson`, whereas Jackson 2.x uses `com.fasterxml.jackson`. Make sure to import right annotations for `ObjectMapper` you use.

Comment: I have only version 2.x in the classpath and respectively I import 2.x annotations(com.fasterxml.*). I'm not sure how aws lambda executes the jar I provided but I assume that they have different class loader with their own dependencies. And based on the stacktrace on failed deserialization it seems that they are using jackson 2 as well. So it's really strange that it can't "recognize" the annotations.

Comment: @HristoAngelov if so, maybe this is not the reason here. I mentioned it because it is quite common problem, especially as IDEs can offer both Jackson 1.x and 2.x types, if both are in classpath (declared as transitive dependencies often, as Hadoop brings in Jackson 1.x dep)

Comment: What version does AWS Lambda use to serialize the object to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and needed `MyCustomClass` to be taken in and out of the `Lambda Function` correctly so that it can be passed through my `State Machine` in the `Step Function` without any hiccups.

Building off what [Hristo Angelov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48063353/3919340) posted, I was able to get a solution that worked for me and I'm posting it hoping that it will help others that were stuck like I was:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

public class StaticSearchPagingLambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

    LambdaLogger logger = null;
    MyCustomClass myCustomClass = null;

    // Register the JavaTimeModule for LocalDate conversion
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) {    

            myCustomClass = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, MyCustomClass .class);

            // ...
            // Do stuff with myCustomClass
            // ...

            objectMapper.writeValue(outputStream, myCustomClass);
    }
}
```

Even though the JSON string will print out differently with the `ObjectMapper` writing to the `OutPutStream`, when the next lambda function takes it in while going through the `Step Function`, it will still get converted to `LocalDate` correctly.

Make sure that in `MyCustomClass` your `toString()` method prints correctly. My `toString()` method looks like this:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SimpleSearch {

    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;

    // ...
    // Getters and Setters for the LocalDate variables
    // ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new JSONObject(this).toString();
    }

    public SimpleSearch() {}
}
```

then your JSON printouts will always look like this when it gets sent to the lambda and not that other crazy `Jackson` format:

```
{
    "startDate": "2018-11-01",
    "endDate": "2018-11-16"
}
```

Some of the Maven dependencies I used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Hopefully AWS fixes the `Jackson` conversions to be reciprocal, to and from JSON, so that we wouldn't have to resort to these custom conversions anymore.

Answer (score 0):

create getter methods for the properties and put  @JsonProperty on the getter methods.

Comment: That's not the problem. This annotation can be placed on fields as well. And if I map the json in my code it's working. But I don't want to do this, because I want to reduce the boilerplate code in my application.

Comment: I am also using it on properties. I just told you the alternate way. I am using @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty and it works.

Comment: I have tried it- it doesn't work. For some reason aws lambda's jackson is not recognizing the annotations.

Comment: I also have problems with AWS Lambda & Jackson. I'm using `@JsonTypeInfo` for inheritence: unit tests are ok, but it fails with lambda with `problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information`. I'm trying to use https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson with AWS Lambda...